# Any way to see output of pv when run in subshell?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a `squashfs` file using `dd` to create a pseudo file - like [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/52247) ("under Streaming Compression" heading):

```
mkdir empty-dir
mksquashfs empty-dir squash.img -p 'sda_backup.img f 444 root root dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M'
```

But I would like to see the progress of how much of the drive has been copied, eg like this would:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M | pv > sda_backup.img
```

It's similar in my mind to if I was trying to verify that an image was taken correctly:

```
cmp <(dd if=/dev/sda | pv) <(cat sda_backup.img)
```

In this case I don't see the output from `pv`.

Is there a way to see the output from `pv` in the subshell?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the native [`dd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) progress counter ;  the `status=progress` flag?

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress
```

which should show periodic updates like:

```
2051014656 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 15.602310 s, 131 MB
```

Comment: Although I am surprised that actually works, and thanks for that, but I'd also like to know how to get `pv` to work for my own understanding and the use of other commands in subshells.

Comment: I don't really understand why `status=progress` works but `pv` doesn't - what is different between how they are outputting the progress messages?

Comment: I have no idea but I think the root might be  that mksquashfs expects a programme to run and shell constructs simply don’t get interpreted as such